# Angular OAuth2 integration

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, angular5

I am working on a springboot + angular project. And I am implementing oauth for the same.
My Spring boot Oauth services(oauth/token) works fine as expected and was tested in postman successfully. But as am trying to integrate that url with angular, i am continuously facing some trouble. I am always getting 401 unauthorized.

My Angular code is as below

```
  login(userName:any,password:any){
    console.log("logged in");
   let params = new URLSearchParams();     
   params.set('username','1522856566577');     
   params.set('password','sens!tiveP@ss');      
   params.set('grant_type','password'); 
   params.set('client_id','clientIdPassword');
   params.set('client_secret','secret');
   params.set('scope','read');
   let headers = new HttpHeaders().
   append('Content-type','application/x-www form-urlencoded; 
           charset=utf- 8').
   append('Authorization','Basic ' 
      +btoa("clientIdPassword:secret"));
     let options = {
        headers:headers
                 };

  this.http.post('/api/oauth/token',params.toString(), options).subscribe(data => console.log(data),err => console.log('Invalid Credentials')); }}
```

Comment: There is nothing to do with Spring Integration in your question: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration. Please, be careful choosing tags.

Comment: Okay, i just changed the topic to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending headers from angular, Api needs to allow origins of requests. Add this code in Spring Boot controller above the class like below. After that Api will be allowed to get headers.

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
    @RestController
    public class AuthenticationController {
        //services...
    }
```

Comment: This is done still i was facing issues. Then i realized the problem was with my ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter. The antmatchers in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter where considered of higher precedence than the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I changed antmatchers in my resource server and finally resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting client id and secret twice in headers and url search params.try the following code to generate tokens in the service

```
getToken()
{

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('your_client_id:your_client_pass')

        })
      };


      var body = "grant_type=client_credentials";



      return this.http.post('your_url',body,
        httpOptions)
        .pipe(map(res=>res.json()));

}
```